# How to create a zoned of gradation area on the edge of ROI in opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a binary image (white and black), the where Region of Interest (ROI) is black. The shape of ROI is irregular and the location of ROI can be anywhere in the frame.

I want to have a smooth gradation at the edge of the ROI (black -> dark grey -> grey -> light grey -> white).

I research the links below, however those cannot solve my problem:

1. [How to blur some portion of Image in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30101044/how-to-blur-some-portion-of-image-in-android)
2. [OpenCV - How to achieve a gradual image blur effect？](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41609662/opencv-how-to-achieve-a-gradual-image-blur-effect)
3. [Combining 2 images with transparent mask in opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36216702/combining-2-images-with-transparent-mask-in-opencv?newreg=e21e4aefb2b44a0e88e2954912be0cbe)
4. [Gradient mask blending in opencv python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42594993/gradient-mask-blending-in-opencv-python/48274875#48274875)

Example of ROI - original image, the REAL Shape is irregular and Location is anywhere:

[image: example of ROI - original image, the REAL Shape is irregular and Location is anywhere]

Expected result - in the edge of ROI the is gradation part changing from stright line to dash line: black -> dark grey -> grey -> light grey -> white:

[image: expectation image - in the edge of ROI the is gradation part changing from stright line to dash line: black -> dark grey -> grey -> light grey -> white]

Comment: Are you looking for [distance transform](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/dbd/tutorial_distance_transform.html) ?

Comment: Seems it is not my expectation. I want to keep the size and shape of ROI almost the same, and only a little part in the edge, e.g. 15 pixel the gradation area is located. I have using GaussianBlur() to make the edge smoother however the smooth part did not contain gradation from black to white.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @han using Gaussian blur **will** have a gradient change from black to white. How else do you want your result?

Comment: Do you want the gradient inside the black or outside the black region

Comment: @JeruLuke my expectation the gradient will have a zone. I think it has been answered by fmw42.

Comment: @fmw42 if I want the gradient inside the black region should I invert black region into white color and vice verse before I apply the distance transform? I've tried change parameter distanceType and maskSize in cv2.distanceTransform() but the gradient seems outside the black region.

Comment: Yes, inverts so rectangle is white and outside is black. The documentation says "Calculates the distance to the closest zero pixel for each pixel of the source image."

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do that for an outer gradient in Python/OpenCV.

```
 - Read the input
 - Convert to grayscale
 - Threshold to binary
 - Apply a distance transform
 - Stretch it to full dynamic range
 - Stretch to limit the gradient to a short distance around the rectangle
 - Save the output
```

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import skimage.exposure

# read image
img = cv2.imread('rect_black.jpg')

# convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold to binary
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# apply distance transform
distimg = cv2.distanceTransform(thresh, cv2.DIST_L2, 3)

# scale distance image to full dynamic range
distimg = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(distimg, in_range='image', out_range=(0,255)).astype(np.uint8)

# scale distance image to form limited gradient border
result = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(distimg, in_range=(0,25), out_range=(0,255)).astype(np.uint8)

# save result
cv2.imwrite('rect_black_distance.png',distimg)
cv2.imwrite('rect_black_result.png',result)

# show the images
cv2.imshow("distance", distimg)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Stretched Distance Image:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Note: In place of the distance transform, one could just use a Gaussian blur.

Comment: Wow, didn't know there was a range limit to apply the gradient border +1

Comment: It is just another stretch that compresses the gradient.