# How to tweak my code to get this smoother/fatter distance map using cv2.distanceTransform?

Tags: python, opencv

I was reading a paper that used distance transform to get a probability map, as shown below:
[image]
using the binary image:
[image]
The map by the paper is so much more "concentrated and filled" (notice the fatter yellow and no pointy lines), compared to mine:
[image]

According to the paper, this is what it's described as:

> ...convert them to continuous distance maps by a distance transform
> and normalize them from 0 to 1 to form a probability map

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

m = np.zeros((720, 1280), dtype=np.uint8)
pts = np.array([[320, 360], [640, 360], [960, 360]])
# rectangle size
rh, rw = 100, 120

for x, y in pts:
    m = cv2.rectangle(m, (int(x - rw / 2), int(y - rh / 2)), (int(x + rw / 2), int(y + rh / 2)), (255, 255, 255), -1)
m = cv2.distanceTransform(m, cv2.DIST_L2, cv2.DIST_MASK_5)
plt.imshow(m)
```

Any idea how to tweak my code to get closer to what the paper did?

Comment: different calculations. they assume 100% inside, and distance drops off towards the outside. your calculation assumes 0% outside, and grows inside. -- invert your mask, calculate distance, then calculate 1/distance or 100-distance or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first invert your image `m`, so that your boxes become black. Then perform distance threshold:

```
inv_m = cv2.bitwise_not(m)
dist_img = cv2.distanceTransform(inv_m, cv2.DIST_L2, 3)
norm_img = cv2.normalize(dist_img, dist_img, 0, 1.0, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
```

Using `scikit image` library, scale the range of intensity to 255:

```
scale_img = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(norm_img, in_range='image', out_range=(0,255)).astype(np.uint8)
```

[image]

Now create a range within this intensity scale, here I chose input range of (0-30). And then invert it:

```
scale_img2 = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(scale_img, in_range=(0,30), out_range=(0,255)).astype(np.uint8)
final_img = cv2.bitwise_not(scale_img2)
```

[image]

This post is based on a [recent answer by fmw42](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71778123/how-to-create-a-zoned-of-gradation-area-on-the-edge-of-roi-in-opencv-python)

Comment: The gradient rescaling is a neat trick!! Just solely inverse them makes them appear very abrupt on the edge. Thanks for this fantastic answer :)